# Input Listener Java [Android Studio]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating an Android Application which gets the text from Input (EditText) and sets the text of Preview (TextView) to the input based on when the user is typing. I know that there is a setOnKeyListener, however that is for specific keys, is it possible to detect any key?

Here is a preview of the App.

[image]

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You can use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Comment: @AndrewBrooke, I think you should post your comment as an answer so it could be marked as one.

Comment: Don't add irrelevant tags.  It might get more attention for the question, but not from the people you want.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Ok, no worries. I will do that next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) class to implement this.

```
final TextView preview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        preview.setText(editable);
    }
});
```